# How to control storyboard segue

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue

I created a segue using storyboard which links the login button to the view which is supposed to be opened when a user logs in. My problem is i have to do a network call and show a loader when a user clicks this button. Only when login is successful thats when i want to go to the next view else it should show an alert message saying unable to login.

The problem is i cant seem to stop the storyboard sugue for me to perform necessary calls before going to the next view.

This is my code :

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loginSuccessSugue"{
          let spinner = self.showLoader(view: self.view)
          self.makeApiCall()
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the segue from controller (rather than button) to controller and perform it in code when your login completes.

Comment: how will i call the segue when im using it

Comment: `func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?)`

Comment: that worked fine can u put it as an answer so that i can make it as correct and u get the relevant points

Comment: Hmmm...looks like we attracted a parasite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: "loginSuccessSugue", sender: self)` after completion of your login calls.